# Как разделить хранение данных одного столбца на два столбца?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть 2 таблицы. В первой хранится информация об участниках мероприятий и их роли на отделениях мероприятия. Называется "Participants". И вторая таблица, где хранится информация об отделении мероприятия. Называется "Branches".

Participants

```
CREATE TABLE `Participants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idBran` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Branches

```
CREATE TABLE `Branches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nameBran` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Хотелось бы поле **idBran** сделать внешним ключом на таблицу Branches, но это не получится т.к. в данный момент в поле **idBran** могут хранится не только id конкретного отделения, но и 0. Этот 0 означает, что роль участника такова, что не требует участия в конкретном отделении. Например, *организатор* или *помощник организатора*. Каким образом можно это исправить, чтобы была более верная структура таблиц? Можно с использованием доп. таблицы.

Comment: Null вместо нуля вполне решает проблему.

Comment: @Akina, да, но как обойтись без пустых значений? Чтобы был только id?

Comment: Ввести запись в таблицу мероприятий, у которой `id=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, Null, вместо 0 вполне решает проблему, как и подсказал Akina, но хотелось бы обойтись без пустых или подобных значений. Этого можно добиться, если ввести таблицу вип-участники или организаторы. Null, хоть и проще использовать в этой структуре, но правильнее, на мой взгляд, сделать доп. таблицу. Из неё и выбирать будет легче. Коды таблиц не поменяются, но поменяется информация, которая будет в них записываться:

Доп. таблица VipParticipants:

```
CREATE TABLE `VipParticipants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vipRole` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```